# JMX is not enabled to receive remote connection

Tags: cassandra

I was trying to connect to nodetool remotely , which fails to connect

```
H:\ApacheCassandra\apache-cassandra-2.1.8-bin\apache-cassandra-2.1.8\bin>nodetool -h 192.168.0.45  status
Starting NodeTool
nodetool: Failed to connect to '192.168.0.45:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused: connect'.
```

I followed couple of option given on net such as

```
Enabled : JMX_PORT="7199"
Enabled : JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.045"
```

in `cassandra-env.sh`

Comment: The hostname `192.168.045` in the options seems to be missing a period.

Comment: it was a type , its 192168.0.45

Answer (score 1):

Did you set everything as instructed [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/security/secureJmxAuthentication.html)?

The default settings are for local JMX only.

For example, did you set LOCAL_JMX=no in cassandra-env.sh?

Comment: forget to mention , Cassandra is running on windows Server 2012 64x. As you mentioned about the instruction , i am not able to find jmxremote.password.template anywhere on the system. LOCAL_JMX=no is set to no.

Comment: Did you try running "netstat -an" to see if Cassandra is listening on port 7199?

Comment: yes. 
tcp 127.0.0.1:7199 (local address) ..I believe it should run as 192.168.0.45:7199

Comment: i dont understand why on startup it says JMX is not enabled

Comment: LOCAL_JMX=no
Active Connections
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    127.0.0.1:7199         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51498        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51499        127.0.0.1:7199         TIME_WAIT